# Get height of DOM element in LESS/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, less

I have a list of elements which I want to delete with an onclick. It give the element an extra css class which hides the element. The class in css says that the element will dissapear using an animation (FadeOutLeft) using [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/).

```
@keyframes fadeOutLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
}
```

}

The problem is that I cant use a "display:none" at 100%. I don't know why but it just doesnt work. So what I want to do is give the 100% a margin-bottom:-{height of the current element}px and also I also want to set the "translateX()" to that value. So what I have to do is get the height of the element there in less. Is this possible with using javascript In Less?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do runtime evaluation in LESS since LESS just compiles to CSS. Your best bet is to make an animation that applies the `display: none;` eventually. Or do the whole thing in JavaScript ;)

Comment: And, wouldnt it be possible to, in any way. Get the height with javascript, keep that value and use it later in less?

Comment: You can do this super simple with jQuery, so: yes? Look at `.animate`